# Configuration issues when generating schedule of flexible routines without overlapping other events, when optimizing on specific constraints

Tags: java, schedule, optaplanner, timefold

First of all, sorry for this long ass question, but I am trying to include all relevant facts for getting accurate help with my configuration. If yet I am missing something, I'm happy to clarify!

I’m trying to use Timefold to schedule user-created routines into a calendar repeatedly, avoiding clashes with existing fixed events in the calendar.

The fixed events have set `start` and `end` dates and are problem facts.

The routines to be scheduled are supposed to be somewhat flexible so we can create a schedule even if the calendar is already quite full with fixed events. For this, the routine configurations have the problem facts `minDuration` and `maxDuration`, and given `timeRanges` in which they can be scheduled, e.g. `Monday 12-5pm`, `Tuesday 9-3pm`, `Friday 12-9pm`. Nonetheless this doesn't mean the routine should be scheduled every Monday, Tuesday and Friday during these times, but rather once a week in between any one of the `timeRanges`.
Therefore what I want to solve for are `start` and `duration`/`end` (though I discovered I can model the constraints more easily if I use duration) problem variables for a list of `routines` (planning entities).

The value range providers I use are bound on the entities, as they differ based on the routine configuration. The `start` VRP is a `CompositeCountableValueRange` joining all start timestamps of the time ranges.
The `duration` VRP creates a Long VR between `minDuration` and `maxDuration`. Both valueRangeProviders have a 5 minute increment, because I don't want routines to start at e.g. 11:38 and don't need minute granularity.

I have setup a hard penalty for partially scheduled routines (only start OR duration set), hard overlap penalties between routines and fixedEvents and between two routines (RoutineInstance::getEnd is a simple helper that adds `duration` to `start`):

```java
private Constraint fixedEventRoutineOverlap(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
  return constraintFactory.forEach(FixedEvent.class)
        .join(
                RoutineInstance.class,
                Joiners.overlapping(
                  FixedEvent::getStart,
                  FixedEvent::getEnd,
                  RoutineInstance::getStart,
                  RoutineInstance::getEnd
                ))
        .penalize(HardSoftLongScore.ONE_HARD)
        .asConstraint("FixedEvent-Routine overlap");
}

private Constraint routinesOverlap(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
  return constraintFactory.forEach(RoutineInstance.class)
        .join(
                RoutineInstance.class,
                Joiners.overlapping(
                  RoutineInstance::getStart,
                  RoutineInstance::getEnd
                ),
                Joiners.filtering((a, b) -> a.getConfiguration().getId() != b.getConfiguration().getId() || a.getInstanceIndex() != b.getInstanceIndex())
          ).penalize(HardSoftLongScore.ONE_HARD)
          .asConstraint("Routines overlap");
}
```

... and soft constraints maximizing the count of scheduled routines and the routine durations.

```java
private Constraint maximizeRoutinesScheduled(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
  return constraintFactory.forEach(RoutineInstance.class)
          .filter(RoutineInstance::isScheduled)
          .reward(HardSoftLongScore.ONE_SOFT)
          .asConstraint("Maximize Routines scheduled");
}

private Constraint maximizeRoutineDurations(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
  return constraintFactory.forEach(RoutineInstance.class)
          .filter(RoutineInstance::isScheduled)
          .reward(HardSoftLongScore.ONE_SOFT)
          .asConstraint("Maximize Routine durations");
}
```

For now, I'm just testing with a simple setup of 3 fixed events and one routine configuration:

```java
RoutineConfiguration routine1 = new RoutineConfiguration(UUID.randomUUID(), 1, Duration.ofMinutes(30), Duration.ofHours(2), 2, List.of(
        new TimeRange(LocalDateTime.of(2023, 7, 4, 9, 0), LocalDateTime.of(2023, 7, 4, 18, 0)),
        new TimeRange(LocalDateTime.of(2023, 7, 5, 9, 0), LocalDateTime.of(2023, 7, 5, 18, 0))
));
```

Just running this with the default optimization settings yields me a result, however it is not optimal (I expect one instance at 11-12:30 4/7/23, the other at 9:00-11:00 5/7/23):

```
Solved schedule: Schedule{fixedEvents=[FixedEvent{start=2023-07-04T10:00, end=2023-07-04T11:00}, FixedEvent{start=2023-07-04T12:30, end=2023-07-04T16:30}, FixedEvent{start=2023-07-05T12:00, end=2023-07-05T18:00}], routineInstances=[RoutineInstance{configurationId='43b28b84-9785-4904-b77d-1cb52a8cae4a', instanceIndex=0, start=2023-07-05T09:55, duration=7200}, RoutineInstance{configurationId='43b28b84-9785-4904-b77d-1cb52a8cae4a', instanceIndex=1, start=2023-07-04T16:45, duration=3000}], score=0hard/10202soft}
Explanation: Explanation of score (0hard/10202soft):
    Constraint match totals:
        2soft: constraint (Maximize Routines scheduled) has 2 matches:
            1soft: justifications ([RoutineInstance{configurationId='43b28b84-9785-4904-b77d-1cb52a8cae4a', instanceIndex=0, start=2023-07-05T09:55, duration=7200}])
            1soft: justifications ([RoutineInstance{configurationId='43b28b84-9785-4904-b77d-1cb52a8cae4a', instanceIndex=1, start=2023-07-04T16:45, duration=3000}])
        10200soft: constraint (Maximize Routine durations) has 2 matches:
            3000soft: justifications ([RoutineInstance{configurationId='43b28b84-9785-4904-b77d-1cb52a8cae4a', instanceIndex=1, start=2023-07-04T16:45, duration=3000}])
            7200soft: justifications ([RoutineInstance{configurationId='43b28b84-9785-4904-b77d-1cb52a8cae4a', instanceIndex=0, start=2023-07-05T09:55, duration=7200}])
    Indictments:
        3001soft: indicted object (RoutineInstance{configurationId='43b28b84-9785-4904-b77d-1cb52a8cae4a', instanceIndex=1, start=2023-07-04T16:45, duration=3000}) has 2 matches:
            1soft: constraint (Maximize Routines scheduled)
            3000soft: constraint (Maximize Routine durations)
        7201soft: indicted object (RoutineInstance{configurationId='43b28b84-9785-4904-b77d-1cb52a8cae4a', instanceIndex=0, start=2023-07-05T09:55, duration=7200}) has 2 matches:
            1soft: constraint (Maximize Routines scheduled)
            7200soft: constraint (Maximize Routine durations)
```

I get a result reliably, however I assume it just finds it randomly, hence the random start times.

One solution I tried, was adding a soft constraint to minimize start times:

```java
private Constraint minimizeRoutineStartTimes(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(RoutineInstance.class)
            .filter(RoutineInstance::isScheduled)
            .penalizeLong(HardSoftLongScore.ONE_SOFT, debugConstraint("Minimize Routine start times SOFT-", r -> {
              if (r.getConfiguration().getEarliestPossibleStart() == null) return 0;
              return ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(r.getConfiguration().getEarliestPossibleStart(), r.getStart());
            }))
            .asConstraint("Minimize Routine start times");
}
```

The other one, was using sorted valueSelectors for start and duration (since this would mean - by my interpretation - that the solver would first try the lowest start time, highest duration, 2nd lowest start time, 2nd highest duration and so on).
Using this solver configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver xmlns="https://timefold.ai/xsd/solver" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="https://timefold.ai/xsd/solver https://timefold.ai/xsd/solver/solver.xsd">
    <solutionClass>org.lucatk.tempus.scheduler.Schedule</solutionClass>
    <entityClass>org.lucatk.tempus.domain.RoutineInstance</entityClass>

    <scoreDirectorFactory>
        <constraintProviderClass>org.lucatk.tempus.scheduler.ScheduleConstraintProvider</constraintProviderClass>
    </scoreDirectorFactory>

    <termination>
        <secondsSpentLimit>60</secondsSpentLimit>
    </termination>

    <constructionHeuristic>
        <queuedEntityPlacer>
            <unionMoveSelector>
                <changeMoveSelector>
                    <entitySelector>
                        <entityClass>org.lucatk.tempus.domain.RoutineInstance</entityClass>
                    </entitySelector>
                    <valueSelector variableName="start">
                        <cacheType>STEP</cacheType>
                        <selectionOrder>SORTED</selectionOrder>
                        <sorterComparatorClass>org.lucatk.tempus.scheduler.EarliestStartComparator</sorterComparatorClass>
                    </valueSelector>
                </changeMoveSelector>
                <changeMoveSelector>
                    <entitySelector>
                        <entityClass>org.lucatk.tempus.domain.RoutineInstance</entityClass>
                    </entitySelector>
                    <valueSelector variableName="duration">
                        <cacheType>STEP</cacheType>
                        <selectionOrder>SORTED</selectionOrder>
                        <sorterComparatorClass>org.lucatk.tempus.scheduler.LongestDurationComparator</sorterComparatorClass>
                    </valueSelector>
                </changeMoveSelector>
            </unionMoveSelector>
        </queuedEntityPlacer>
    </constructionHeuristic>

    <localSearch>
        <unionMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
                <entitySelector>
                    <entityClass>org.lucatk.tempus.domain.RoutineInstance</entityClass>
                </entitySelector>
                <valueSelector variableName="start">
                    <cacheType>STEP</cacheType>
                    <selectionOrder>SORTED</selectionOrder>
                    <sorterComparatorClass>org.lucatk.tempus.scheduler.EarliestStartComparator</sorterComparatorClass>
                </valueSelector>
            </changeMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
                <entitySelector>
                    <entityClass>org.lucatk.tempus.domain.RoutineInstance</entityClass>
                </entitySelector>
                <valueSelector variableName="duration">
                    <cacheType>STEP</cacheType>
                    <selectionOrder>SORTED</selectionOrder>
                    <sorterComparatorClass>org.lucatk.tempus.scheduler.LongestDurationComparator</sorterComparatorClass>
                </valueSelector>
            </changeMoveSelector>
        </unionMoveSelector>
    </localSearch>
</solver>
```

However, both approaches just result in the solver running infinitely.
With the minimization constraint, I can't really identify what it's doing (just random steps), however with the valueSelector approach, it seems like it's always cycling the first two values of the ranges instead of "remembering" the value didn't provide a solution.

So, my problem is, I set up the solver to the best of my abilities, but I am not able to pinpoint what issues my configuration could have so as to not reach a valid solution.

Comment: Could you please clarify why both the `start` and `duration` are planning variables? I would expect that the `RoutineInstance`  comes with a fixed duration (e.g. average duration or worst case duration per routine type) and the planning variable is only its `start`.
As for the solver running infinitely, have you tried turning on `debug` (shows steps) and then also `trace` (shows evaluated moves) logging?

Comment: @RadovanSynek certainly, as opposed to how a routine may be defined in other cases, in my application I want the duration to be flexible, depending on how busy the schedule is - e.g. imagine a routine "Yoga" with min duration 30mins, max 2hrs. If there's enough space in the schedule it should schedule e.g. a 2hrs or 1,5hrs session whereas if the schedule is already busy, it would maybe fit in at least a 30 mins session.

Comment: I have definitely looked at the debug logs but can't really identify any indication for what I'm doing wrong - attached for [solution 1](https://gist.github.com/lucatk/decab81a53981afdd50599528372ce56#file-log_solution1-txt) and [solution 2](https://gist.github.com/lucatk/decab81a53981afdd50599528372ce56#file-log_solution2-txt)

Comment: I've now configured a cartesianProductMoveSelector to make start and duration changes in one step. Again - if I use sorted selection, what happens is that it only cycles the initial values in the moves, never proceeding - see this [log](https://gist.github.com/lucatk/c28984b71fdb91bb66e0732d7f284b51)